# Svcutil --update error output not making sense

Tags: svcutil.exe

I am trying to update a soap service reference using svcutil.

I have tried:

```
 dotnet svcutil -u --projectFile "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
```

Which gives the nonsensical error:

```
Warning: The specified --projectFile option is not expected in the current operational context of the tool!
Error: The --update option requires a project to be specified, please use the --projectFile option to specify the project to use.
```

And:

```
dotnet svcutil -u --projectFile "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyServiceFolder"
```

Same Error

And I have tried:

```
dotnet svcutil -u --projectFile "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyServiceFolder\dotnet-svcutil.params.json"
```

Same error.

I have even tried:

```
dotnet svcutil -u "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\Nexus.Services.csproj"
```

and

```
dotnet svcutil -u "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyServiceFolder"
```

But that gives the error:

```
Error: The --update option requires a project to be specified, please use the --projectFile option to specify the project to use.
```

I cannot find a single example anywhere of how this command should be run.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a service reference using `dotnet svcutil --update ...`, it needs to find both the project file *and* the service reference configuration.

From the help `dotnet-svcutil --help`:

> `--projectFile <project file>` The project file to add the client to (if any). (Short Form: `-pf`).
> `--update <web service reference>` Updates an existing web service reference. If the project contains more than one web service reference, the name of the web service reference to be updated is required. (Short Form: `-u`).

When you run the `svcutil` in a different directory than the one containing your project file, you will need to tell it explicitly where your project is using `--projectFile`.

So, the easiest solution is to run the update command from the directory containing your project and specify where the service reference is:

```
dotnet svcutil -u .\path\to\ServiceReference
```

You can specify the path of the directory containig the `dotnet-svcutil.params.json` file, or an explicit path to a config file.

From the examples printed when running `dotnet svcutil -h`:

> `dotnet-svcutil -u ServiceReference`
>
> - Update existing web service reference named ServiceReference. The command need to be executed under directory which contains the project file.

Comment: So after many trial and errors, the key here is to provide the folder path to the service reference.  To save anyone else a lot of grief, here is an example:
 dotnet svcutil -u "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyServiceFolder" --projectFile "C:\projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"